# WCF transport security over NetTcpBinding: how to verify data encryption?

Tags: encryption, wcf-security

I use transport security over nettcpbinding. How can I verify data over the wire is really encrypted? I tried wireshark, but since data is in binary format without encryption, I cannot distinguish non-encrypted-binary-data and encrypted-binary-data.

Thanks a lot!